# After calling jQuery load or $.ajax with datatype html element does not update

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am currently having a problem where when the jQuery Load is called an element which was previously updateable is no longer updateable it reverts to its original state and although it is still accessible and updateable the visual on the screen does not change.

The element is in the a partial view in the layout page. While the load event is being called from a click in a `<li>` menu item. Which then calls load and attempts to get the possible changes in cart.

[image]

**Partial View Code**

```
<div id="cart" style="float:right;clear:right;margin-top:31px;height:21px;">
    <span>
        <a href='/ShoppingCart/ShoppingCart'><img style='height:16px;margin-bottom:5px;' src='../Content/images/cartImage.gif' alt='cart' />0 Total : 0</a> 
    </span>
</div>
```

**Layout Code**

```
function GetCart() {
    var url = "/ShoppingCart/GetCartAmount/";
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        data: {},
        cache: false,
        type: "POST",
        success: function (result) {
            var markup = "<span> <a href='/ShoppingCart/ShoppingCart'><img style='height:16px;margin-bottom:5px;' src='../Content/images/cartImage.gif' alt='cart'/></a> " +
                result.ItemCount + "  Total: " + result.Total + "</span>";

            $("#cart").html(markup);
            alert($('#cart').html());

            alert("after set");
        },
        error: function (reponse) {
            alert("error : " + reponse);
        }
    });
}
```

The Ajax code is in a function with other processing.

```
$.ajax({
    url: data.redirectUrl,
    dataType: "html",
    success: function (responseText) {
        var tempDiv = $.parseHTML(responseText);
        $("#result").html(tempDiv).show();
    }
});
 GetCart();
```

**Controller Code**

```
<HttpPost()>
Function GetCartAmount() As ActionResult
        Dim ItemCount = GetCart().Count
        Return Json(New With {.Total = GetCartTotal().ToString, .ItemCount = ItemCount})
End Function

Public Function GetCart() As List(Of WebItemModel)
        Dim retValue As New List(Of WebItemModel)
        If Session("Cart") IsNot Nothing Then
            retValue = DirectCast(Session("Cart"), List(Of WebItemModel))
        End If
        Return retValue
End Function
```

If any further code should be provided please do tell me. I didn't post it all since it would take up too much space and possibly confuse people. Also to make a point it initially works before the jQuery load occurs.

Comment: It seems odd to be replacing the entire shopping cart with the results of the ajax call. You will need to show all the code (and page HTML) to put your example into context.

Comment: Can you show the code for the click event which is not working?

Comment: Can you show the `/ShoppingCart/GetCartAmount/` what is returning because what I understand from your question is that you want to return the partialview after a click, with a simple `.load()` jquery is enough but please update with `GetCartAmount` action

Comment: @JorgeF I have added more code and an image to help clarify the red square area doesn't update after click one of the <li> items >

Comment: Do you have any errors in the the debug console (chrome or firefox)? The `GetCartAmount` should return what you expected in the debugger (in this case is a json string)

Comment: @JorgeF I had placed an alert() and it seems to be updating but for some reason on screen there is no change.Also just checked just to confirm and the console shows the json of GetCartAmount() as it should be.

Comment: You are using `$("#result").html(tempDiv).show();` what are you doing there? just updating a div? And in your return json try to specify `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet` in case it's blocking the data return from json. If that does not work, try to update your partialview instead of changing the html

Comment: @JorgeF I was able to update the partial view finally with the following code    
    
     `function GetCart() {
      var url = "/ShoppingCart/Cart/";

      var $partialDiv = $('#PartialCart div')

      $.get(url, function (data) {
             $partialDiv.replaceWith(data);
          });
      }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it working by doing the following

```
function GetCart() {
    var url = "/ShoppingCart/Cart/";

    var $partialDiv = $('#PartialCart div')

    $.get(url, function (data) {
         $partialDiv.replaceWith(data);
    });
}
```

It seems to be working perfectly now the replaceWith did the trick for me.

**Controller Code**

```
Public Function GetCart() As List(Of WebItemModel)
        Dim retValue As New List(Of WebItemModel)
        If Session("Cart") IsNot Nothing Then
            retValue = DirectCast(Session("Cart"), List(Of WebItemModel))
        End If
        Return retValue
End Function
```